# Sublime text linux gcc build for simple C programs

Tags: linux, gcc, sublimetext2

I want to build programs in the inbuilt build command of sublime text 2

I've made a gcc.sublime-build file with

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell":true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

but all i get is an error saying

gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 4]

any ideas

Answer (score 5):

Sublime Text is executing `gcc` without parameters because `"shell": true` means that the value of `"cmd"` is passed to a shell, and it should be one string. In your file it appears that you want to pass parameters directly to GCC, so you should set `"shell"` to `false`.

Comment: @DickWthomas might be away but the answer remains the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
all: source
```

Then, type `make`.